# How to get the component out of the DragAndDropWrapper again

Tags: drag-and-drop, components, vaadin

I was following [this guide](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.dragndrop.html#advanced.dragndrop.dragging) in order to achieve a solution for my drag and drop scenario. Basically I've an component ([Slider](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Slider.html)) wrapped in a "[DragAndDropWrapper](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/DragAndDropWrapper.html)". This works pretty well.

```
                final Slider slider = new Slider(title);
                slider.setValue(1.0);
                slider.setWidth("100%");
                slider.setMax(4);
                slider.addStyleName("ticks");

                final DragAndDropWrapper sliderWrap = new DragAndDropWrapper(slider);
                sliderWrap.setDragStartMode(DragStartMode.COMPONENT);
                sliderWrap.setSizeUndefined();
                ((AbstractOrderedLayout) this.getContent()).addComponent(sliderWrap);
```

Okay, to simplify things let's assume we have a [button](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Button.html) wrapped in such a [DragAndDropWrapper](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/DragAndDropWrapper.html).

```
final Button button = new Button("An Absolute Button");

final DragAndDropWrapper buttonWrap = new DragAndDropWrapper(button);
buttonWrap.setDragStartMode(DragStartMode.COMPONENT);
```

How am I supposed to get the button out of there again? I'm searching for something like this:

```
Button myButton = buttonWrap.getComponent(0);
```

The [API](https://vaadin.com/api/) doesn't state any method which can be used to do so (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getCompositionRoot method](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/CustomComponent.html#getCompositionRoot%28%29) . Unfortunately, this method is protected so you will need to extend DragAndDropWrapper and change method visibility. Example:

```
public class MyDragAndDropWrapper extends DragAndDropWrapper
{
    public MyDragAndDropWrapper(Grid grid)
    {
        super(grid);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getCompositionRoot(){
        return super.getCompositionRoot();
    }
}
//...later on
Grid grid = new Grid(container);
grid.setId("fancyId");
MyDragAndDropWrapper w  = new MyDragAndDropWrapper(grid);
System.out.println(w.getCompositionRoot().getId());
layout.addComponent(w);
```

Remember you can always declare variable `w` in above code as original `DragAndDropWrapper` and access `getCompositionRoot` via casting.